# UIWebView's shouldStartLoadWithRequest doesn't called sometimes

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I am using a `UIWebView` in my app and I am overriding the `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` message to detect what kind of link is being clicked. If it's a "special" link, I push a `UIViewController` onto the stack and return NO from this method. This works just dandy most of the time.

Sometimes, however, I click on a link and my `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` never gets called. Now what's weird is that the UIViewController which houses the `UIWebView` is in a `UITabBarController` and when I click on another tab, the UIWebView finally gets its `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` called. Until I click this other tab, I do NOT get a call to `shouldStartLoadWithRequest`. The other interesting bit is that the failure case never happens the first time I click on a link; it's always on a subsequent time.

Has anyone seen this? To me, this sounds like the `UIWebView` is, sometimes, not getting a touchEnded event and by switching tabs, the underlying framework is forcing a touchEnded event which in turn causes my `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` to get called.

Answer (score 0):

Are you implementing the

```
– webView:didFailLoadWithError:
```

method from the UIWebViewDelegate?  Perhaps you're getting an error on the request and then you're never seeing it?  This delegate should get thrown when you have issue such as timeouts and other things.

Comment: I was. I ended up reworking this code to use native UITableViews so the question is kind of meaningless now :) Thanks for the help though.